# Cursor vs Iterator pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In numerous texts, I've seen the term cursor used interchangeably with the term iterator. However, it doesn't seem right that they are treated as the same thing.

To me, an iterator allows iteration of a container with no knowledge of the container itself. A cursor, on the other hand, allows iteration of a container as well but has implementation details specific to the container type, so it does keep a reference to the container. Additionally a cursor's interface mirrors the interface of the container kind of like the facade pattern.

Here is an example of what I would consider a cursor:

```
class Book {};

class Library
{
    std::vector<Book> books;

    bool IsBookHardCover( int bookIndex );
    bool IsBookSoftCover( int bookIndex );

    BookCursor GetFirstBook();
};

class BookCursor
{
    std::vector<Book>& books;
    int currentBook;

    bool IsHardCover();
    bool IsSoftCover();

    void Next();
};
```

So basically I make the distinction between iterators and cursors based on their dependency or knowledge of the container they iterate. Is this an appropriate distinction? If not, what would you consider the design pattern I've outlined in my code example above?

Note that my code example above should be treated as pseudocode since I did not compile it and it also lacks the constructors required.

Comment: In many cases an iterator does know the container it is iterating over.  The difference would seem to be in the client code, where an iterator will only expose the iterator interface, whereas your cursor exposes some specific implementation details of your custom container.

Comment: Where did you get this definition of "cursor"?

Comment: What does your cursor pattern achieve that can't be achieved by dereferencing an iterator? In addition, iterator implementations (by necessity) must know something about the container they are iterating over - however operations on iterators only need to know the capabilities of the iterator, nothing about the underlying container.

Comment: I don't think the difference between the two has anything to do with the container's interface. I think that an iterator is a particular case of a cursor. Cursors are broader in purpose, in multidimensional structures a cursor would let you navingate on any direction, much like text editors cursors, or the mouse pointer. On the other hand an iterator is something that will iterate through each single value contained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cursor pattern you described is the combination of two patterns: Proxy and Iterator.  The reason the standard library is different is to avoid needlessly coupling those two behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia redirects Cursor Pattern to the page for [Iterator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_pattern).  With that in mind, I'd say you're splitting hairs.  If we may consider wikipedia to be a definitive reference, the two terms can be used interchangeably.

Comment: If I thought Wikipedia was the "end all be all" resource for everything I wouldn't be asking about it here. The pattern I have described is something. If it's not the cursor pattern, then I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: TBH the Gang of Four "Design Patterns" book says the Iterator pattern is "also known as" the Cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally long before the term design pattern was used, cursers where more powerfull than iterators as they allowed to a bigger extend to modify the underlying datastructure.
Like insertBefore(), insertAfter() or insertAt() etc.
Some implementations allowed it that multiple cursers could operate on the same container and they informed each other about manipulations (they are called stable iterators in our days, or stable data structures)

Answer (score 0):

Iterators (at least the way the are defined in the C++ standard) don't give you access to the properties of the underlying container but those details are accessible to you through the different iterator categories (which are accessible through `iterator_tags`).

I also think your example is flawed. Why would a collection of data mirror the interface of the data (e.g. `IsHardCover()`) when I can access the contained value and query itself for its properties?